# Extract files from online tar archive using only its URL

Tags: linux, tar

I found a tar file on the net that sizes more than 50GB. I only need to extract small stuff (100MB) out of that tar file. I figured out downloading the entire 50GB file for just 100MB is wasteful of my time and bandwidth.

So my question is there any method that I can use to do operations on online tar file (with having URL only) without needing to download the entire tar archive.

Comment: Let say, if for zip or 7z file, then it is possible to do so?

Comment: Contrary to the other comments made, I would venture a guess this would be rather possible.  Basically, you would need an http filesystem driver, so that when tar read some data (like a size of an embedded file), and then knows to skip over that much data, then the filesystem driver could use HTTP to specify bytes (similar to what is done to resume files).  In theory, this could work with specialized software.  In practice, I don't know if software for mounting HTTP sites as a local file actually provide such optimization.  (Even if possible, this might not be done well, or may be HARD to do.)

Comment: The easy solution may be much simpler to pull off, though not being exactly what you asked for.  But I know people do this sort of thing much more frequently:: download the 50GB file to a computer you have with a fast Internet connection (a server at a high speed data center, maybe in a rack at an ISP, or a University's Internet connection), and use that to extract the interesting data, and then copy that data to your computer (which may be over a slower Internet link).

Comment: @TOOGAM I'm the author of the (now deleted) "other comment". You are right, it's possible. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the protocol is HTTP. In my Kubuntu the right tool is [`httpfs2`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/HTTPFS2/).

> `httpfs2` is a FUSE based filesystem for mounting http or https URLS as files in the filesystem. There is no notion of listable directories in http so only a single URL can be mounted. The server must be able to send byte ranges.

If the URL of tar file in question is `http://ser.ver/bar.tar`, proceed as follows:

```
mkdir foo
httpfs2 -f http://ser.ver/bar.tar ./foo
```

I used `-f` (stay in foreground) for two reasons:

1. If there's something wrong, the process exits and I can see this immediately.
2. The process prints to the console, so it's convenient to switch to another console anyway.

Now you should have `./foo/bar.tar` available in your filesystem. The file is seekable and read-only. Extract what you need, then unmount (choose one):

- `fusermount -u ./foo`;
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the console where `httpfs2` runs;
- `killall httpfs2`.

---

I have tested this solution by mounting the following ISO file:

```
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/cdimage/kubuntu/releases/17.10/release/kubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

and browsing it with `ark`.

The second test was with a 30+ GB tar archive hosted from Debian server in my LAN. The archive was created deliberately for this test and I paid attention which files were added near the beginning, which ones near the end. Then on a Kubuntu client I used `mc` to get into the `httpfs2`-mounted archive and copy a file from near the end of the archive. It took a while before the actual copying started (I think `httpfs2` was "fast-forwarding" to the chosen file), then it went flawlessly. I'm sure the whole archive was never sent.

The server process was `apache2`. Similar test with [`python3 -m http.server 80`](https://askubuntu.com/a/377394/693277) failed at the mounting stage; this server was too simple.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you for pointing out how this can be done, but also pointing out that this could fail to work based on what server software is being used.  So while this may work for a file provided by one web server found on the Internet, the ability to skip around files might not be implemented by a different web server.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Thanks for spending your time answering this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

propebly you can't do such a thing.

because an online archived file actually resident on a remote computer, so if you want to do the extraction online, that would be actually the remote host whose doing the job, not your cpu. and to do such a thing, the remote host should offer such an ability to list or extract the archived files, and just then it would be more than just an ftp usage.